# PresenceNotificationReceived RemotePresentityNotification.PersonalNote.Message is empty string when note is changed

Tags: c#, lync-2010, lync, ucma

Right now I have a `RemotePresenceView` for which I subscribe to the `PresenceNotificationReceived` event.  The event is correctly getting fired when I change the presence or note in the Lync Client but when it handles the event the `RemotePresentityNotification.PersonalNote.Message` is an empty string.  The `RemotePresentityNotification.AggregatedPresenceState` is correct but the personal note never is.  What's the deal?

I also have the question posted on the microsoft forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ucmanagedsdk/thread/70f249a8-9f55-4e85-b4e4-bd5d18727b9f/;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this problem is occurring when the OwnerUri for the UserEndpoint that the RemotePresenceView is tied is the same as the PresentityUri for the RemotePresentityNotification.  I fixed it by changing the account for the UserEndpoint.  Here are the example results when I tested setting the note to "Out of town":

1. UserEndpoint.OwnerURI = master.user@test.com, 
   RemotePresentityNotification.PresentityUri = master.user@test.com, 
   Note = ""
2. UserEndpoint.OwnerURI = master.user@test.com, 
   RemotePresentityNotification.PresentityUri = test.user@test.com, 
   Note = "Out of town"
3. UserEndpoint.OwnerURI = test.user@test.com, 
   RemotePresentityNotification.PresentityUri = master.user@test.com, 
   Note = "Out of town"
4. UserEndpoint.OwnerURI = test.user@test.com, 
   RemotePresentityNotification.PresentityUri = test.user@test.com, 
   Note = ""
5. UserEndpoint.OwnerURI = test.user@test.com, 
   RemotePresentityNotification.PresentityUri = secondtest.user@test.com, 
   Note = "Out of town"